# How to make pandas work for cross multiplication

Tags: pandas, numpy, multiplication

I have 3 data frame:

df1

```
id,k,a,b,c
1,2,1,5,1
2,3,0,1,0
3,6,1,1,0
4,1,0,5,0
5,1,1,5,0
```

df2

```
name,a,b,c
p,4,6,8
q,1,2,3
```

df3

```
type,w_ave,vac,yak
n,3,5,6
v,2,1,4
```

from the multiplication, using pandas and numpy, I want to the output in df1:

```
id,k,a,b,c,w_ave,vac,yak
1,2,1,5,1,16,15,18
2,3,0,1,0,0,3,6
3,6,1,1,0,5,4,7
4,1,0,5,0,0,11,14
5,1,1,5,0,13,12,15
```

the conditions are:
The value of the new column will be =

```
#its not a code
df1["w_ave"][1] = df3["w_ave"]["v"]+ df1["a"][1]*df2["a"]["q"]+df1["b"][1]*df2["b"]["q"]+df1["c"][1]*df2["c"]["q"]
for output["w_ave"][1]= 2 +(1*1)+(5*2)+(1*3)
df3["w_ave"]["v"]=2
df1["a"][1]=1, df2["a"]["q"]=1 ;
df1["b"][1]=5, df2["b"]["q"]=2 ;
df1["c"][1]=1, df2["c"]["q"]=3 ;
```

Which means: 
- a new column will be added in df1, from the name of the column from df3. 
- for each row of the df1, the value of a, b, c will be multiplied with the same-named q value from df2. and summed together with the corresponding value of df3. 
-the column name of df1 , matched will column name of df2 will be multiplied. The other not matched column will not be multiplied, like df1[k].
- However, if there is any 0 in df1["a"], the corresponding output will be zero.

I am struggling with this. It was tough to explain also. My attempts are very silly. I know this attempt will not work. However, I have added this:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

data1 = "Sample_data1.csv"
data2 = "Sample_data2.csv"
data3 = "Sample_data3.csv"

folder = '~Sample_data/'
df1 =pd.read_csv(folder + data1)
df2 =pd.read_csv(folder + data2)
df3 =pd.read_csv(folder + data3)

df1= df2 * df1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this will in no way resemble your desired output, but vectorizing the formula you provided:

```py
df2=df2.set_index("name")
df3=df3.set_index("type")
df1["w_ave"] = df3.loc["v", "w_ave"]+ df1["a"].mul(df2.loc["q", "a"])+df1["b"].mul(df2.loc["q", "b"])+df1["c"].mul(df2.loc["q", "c"])
```

Outputs:

```py
   id  k  a  b  c  w_ave
0   1  2  1  5  1     16
1   2  3  0  1  0      4
2   3  6  1  1  0      5
3   4  1  0  5  0     12
4   5  1  1  5  0     13
```

Comment: I do not want to write every column name of df1 and df2, 
df1["w_ave"] = df3.loc["v", "w_ave"]+ df1["a"].mul(df2.loc["q", "a"])+df1["b"].mul(df2.loc["q", "b"])+df1["c"].mul(df2.loc["q", "c"]). Becasue, my real data has too many columns. Is there any way, that if df1 column name match  with df2 column name, then it to do the calculation for the matched column?

Comment: Not really - you can try doing this in ```numpy``` with ```numpy.dot``` - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html (first convert your df to ```numpy```:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) - just try to set up matrix operation, that will suit you, but unless the size of your df is relatively small it will be way slower than the above.